# Magento Cron errors

Tags: php, linux, bash, magento, cron

I have been attempting to fix an issue for a few months now but I never seem to get anywhere. I have little to *no* PHP experience as well as little Magento knowledge.
The site is running Magento version 1.9.2.4.

### Crontab

```
SHELL="/bin/sh" */5     *       *       *       *       /bin/sh /var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.sh
```

I have used plesk to set both my cron.php and cron.sh to convert my line endings to UNIX. Since doing this I receive multiple emails containing errors. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

### Email

```
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or 
directory
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 3: conf: command not 
found
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 4: conf: command not 
found
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 5: conf: command not 
found
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 6: conf: command not 
found
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 7: syntax error near 
unexpected token `('
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.php: line 7: ` * This source file 
is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)'
```

Before this email I was getting emailed different errors for my cron.sh:

```
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.sh: line 48: syntax error near 
unexpected token `fi'
/var/www/vhosts/WEBSITE.com/httpdocs/cron.sh: line 48: `fi'
```

### Code - Cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
# @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
#
# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi
MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
    MODE=" $2"
fi
#PHP_BIN=`which php`
# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`
#   prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

### Code - Cron.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = escapeshellarg(basename(__FILE__));
            $cronPath = escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cron.sh');

            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Please include your code as text (formatted as code) in your answer, not as links to an external website. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Yeah sorry it wasn't quite working and I was getting frustrated with it so I just thought I would upload it somewhere and link it, my bad!

Comment: I'll add an edit suggestion and it will get through. No worries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like the PHP script is getting executed like bash script.
In the cron.sh file on line 36 the PHP_BIN variable is commented out, perhaps uncommenting it should fix the issue.
`` PHP_BIN=`which php` ``

Comment: This worked but now I am receiving this - PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mcrypt_module_open() in /var/www/vhosts/hyroc.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 74

Comment: You don't have mcrypt module enabled. You should be able to enable it with `phpenmod mcrypt `. Also don't forget to restart the web server afterwards.

Comment: If the suggestion above doesn't work make sure to install the php-mcrypt package. For Ubuntu `apt-get install php-mcrypt`. For CentOS `yum install php-mcrypt`